# How do I deserialize an a list of objects from a Memory Stream through WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

MVC 4.0

I have the following running on a service:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetHierarchyReportContents")]
[FaultContract(typeof(InvalidHierarchyNameException))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Node))]
MemoryStream GetContents();
```

This function provides a memory stream which contains a list of Node (APINode because of an alias). Essentially, all it does is the following:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

formatter.Serialize(stream, data.ToList<APINode>());

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return stream;
```

The following is the definition of Node, which is defined in a namespace to prevent conflict with another node.

```
[DataContract (Name="Node",Namespace="API")]
[Serializable]
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

}
```

On my client app, I do the following:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
List<Node> nodes = (List<Node>) bf.Deserialize(client.GetContents());
```

I am getting the error that says:

> Unable to find assembly 'API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

I am using a `wsHttpBinding` for the client connection. 
I must be missing something, perhaps the namespace screws something up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the version of the .NET runtime on your client is any different from that which is on your server, binary serialization will likely fail. I would recommend using `DataContractSerializer` and writing as binary using `XmlDictionaryWriter`:

```
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(stream);
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(List<APINode>);

        serializer.WriteObject(writer, data.ToList<APINode>());
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
```

on the client side:

```
        using (var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(client.GetContents(), XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(List<Node>);

            return (List<Node>)serializer.ReadObject(reader, true);
        }
```

Comment: Getting different error, but I think you are on the right track (besides missing some typeofs on arguments for DataContractSerializer). The new error is "Cannot access a closed Stream." So the reader object either was never opened or closed early. Can't say i've ever used it so I'll have to do some investigation.

Comment: It's possible that the `using` around `var writer`... is closing the `MemoryStream` that's being returned. I'll edit the answer to remove it and see what it does for you.

Comment: New error around the read: Expecting element 'ArrayOfNode' from namespace 'namespace'.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''.
I think the issue may lie in the actual writing to the stream though. I starting debugging the writing process and despite there being a node to write, the length of the stream is still 0.

Comment: One more possibility - the stream needs to be "rewound" to the beginning to read properly. Adding in two more lines of code.